# Changes in python.el do not take place in python-mode

Tags: python, indentation, syntax-highlighting

I'm facing the same problem as OP in this question: [How can I make python-mode correctly indent python's match statement?](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/69291/how-can-i-make-python-mode-correctly-indent-pythons-match-statement).

A quote from the OP: "Python 3.10 added a match statement. When I try and type one in emacs 27.2, it does not indent it correctly, presumably because it does not yet have support for it. How do I get python-mode to indent the match statement correctly?"

One contributor suggested `M-x find-library RET python RET` and just append the two keywords (match and case) to appropriate places. I did just that. For a while Emacs was working wonderfully with indenting the match and case statements. However as of now the indentation and block syntax highlighting etc. is not working at all. I have tried loading python.el by `load-file RET RET` but of no avail. Here is an example of my additions:

```
`(rx-let ((block-start       (seq symbol-start
                                    (or "def" "class" "if" "elif" "else" "try"
                                        "except" "finally" "for" "while" "with"
                                        ;; Added by @Keyboard_Crasher.
                                        "match" "case"
                                        ;; Python 3.5+ PEP492
                                        (and "async" (+ space)
                                             (or "def" "for" "with")))
                                    symbol-end))
```

The question is: how to fix this annoying lack of indentation and syntax highlighting?

Comment: Adding this makes indenting works for me.

Comment: If you want to make syntax highlighting work either, try to add `match` and `case` to `python-font-lock-keywords-level-2`

Comment: Great that it works for you! It also worked for me for a while but not anymore. I did add `match` and `case` to the place you mentioned but decided to post only a part of the changes in OP.

Comment: Did you byte compile the python.el file or get rid of the comes-with-emacs .elc file?  The changes you show worked for me (thanks) once I deleted python.elc.   I don't see how it would have worked for awhile and stopped.

Comment: Ah, did recompile `python.el` (with `M-x byte-compile-file`) and now it's working again! Thank you for pointing this out!

Comment: What about emacs v28?  When I run `M-x find-library RET python RET` I get `Can't find library: python`.